give an example of a set that has exactly two accumulation points
I am new to this forum so please bear with me if I miss any information. I am currently taking advanced calculus using the textbook Introduction to Analysis (5th Ed) by Edward Gaughan. I am having a lot of trouble answering the following question:
Give an example of a set of real number which has exactly two accumulation points.
I am super confused about the concept of accumulation points at this point. I don't know if I am overthinking the concept or what, but I really need some help in knowing if my guess is correct
S = {1/n : n∈N} U {1 + 1/n : n∈N},
Claim 0 is a limit point of S, 0 is not an element of S
Given epsilon > 0, find N ∈N such that 0< 1/N< epsilon (by Archimedean principle)
1/N ∈ (0- epsilon, 0 + epsilon) intersection S with 1/n not equal to 0, therefore 0 is a limit point.
Claim 1 is a limit point of S, 1 is not an element of S
Given epsilon > 0, find N ∈N such that 1< 1 + 1/N< epsilon (by Archimedean principle)
1 + 1/N ∈ (1- epsilon, 1 + epsilon) intersection S with 1+ 1/n not equal to 0, therefore 1 is a limit point.
I am really struggling, and I am unsure if this is correct or not.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

An accumulation point of a set is a point that is approached by other points in the set, closer and closer.
Indeed $1/n\to 0$ and $1 + 1/n\to 1$ and the set of points $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{1+1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ does not have other accumulation points: the first set has only one accumulation point because a decreasing sequence has a unique limit, and similarly for the second set.
The fact that there are no other accumulation points rests on this fact: two sets with one unique accumulation point each have as union only those two as accumulation points (assuming they are different.) This can be proven by taking a sequence that converges to a different accumulation point, dividing it into two subsequences (one from the first and one from the second set), noting one must be infinite and still converge, and arriving at a contradiction.

Is it sufficient when doing this to say that x is not equal to 0 or 1 using the rules given and there fore 0 and 1 are the only limit points or do i actually need to show it

If a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$, then either infinite values belong to the first set or the second set, and therefore $x$ is an accumulation point of one of the two sets; thus $x$ is $0$ or $1$.

This would suffice, and is in fact the example that came to mind for me.
An additional thing you should prove is that these are the only two accumulation points. Namely, prove that if $x \notin \{0,1\}$, then $x$ is not an accumulation point.
You may want to consider a few cases for that, namely being outside $[0,2]$, and then the cases where it's stuck between members of each sequence individually, or is a member itself. You should be able to construct a ball that encapsulates no (other, if need be) members of the set.

As a hint for the OP.  If $w > 2$ then let $\epsilon =w-2$.  Note of $x\in S$ then $x \le 2$ (why?) and what does that say about whether $w-\epsilon < x < w+\epsilon$?  (Hint: $w-\epsilon = 2$.)  Can the OP do the rest for $w < 0$? or $0< w < 1;w\ne \frac 1k$ for any $k$? or $0 < w=\frac 1k < 1$; and so on?
